# Register JS for block on frontend only

Tags: php, block-editor

I'm using the following in PHP to register my custom block:

```
register_block_type( __DIR__, /* block.json */
  array(
    'render_callback' => 'render_my_block',
    'script' => 'my-custom-js',
  )
);
```

The block is registered but the `my-custom-js` JS file is loaded on the frontend and in the backend editor. How can I load it only on the frontend?

I tried `'view_script' => 'my-custom-js'` and `'view-script' => 'my-custom-js'` but it does not work.

I know that I can use `is_admin()` to check if it's in the editor and not load a js file but I'm trying to see how it can be done with `register_block_type()`.

Comment: How do you register the `my-custom-js` script? Isn't the `script` indeed used only to enqueue the script on the front-end? (I mean, the documentation suggests it's so..) Could it be that you accidentally *enqueued* the script manually on the back-end?..

Comment: @SallyCJ this is for `register_block_type`. It loads the script in the backend in the editor as well as frontend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using WordPress 5.8 (e.g. v5.8.3), then I'm afraid the answer to this:

> I know that I can use `is_admin()` to check if it's in the editor and
> not load a js file but I'm trying to see how it can be done with
> `register_block_type()`.

.. is it can't; not in WordPress 5.8.

### More Details

Excerpt from https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-metadata/#view-script: (* note the "**Since**" part that I highlighted)

> #### View Script
>
> - ...
> - Property:  `viewScript`
> - **Since:  `WordPress 5.9.0`**
>
> 1| `{ "viewScript": "file:./build/view.js" }`
>
> Block type frontend script definition. It will be enqueued only when
> viewing the content on the front of the site.

So the `viewScript` property (in `block.json`/JS) or the `view-script` in PHP, didn't work because the property/argument will only be [supported in WordPress 5.9](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/51501) ( props to https://jeremyfelt.com/2021/12/17/some-block-json-minutia/ ).

### Alternate Solution

Apart from only registering the script handle `if ( ! is_admin() )`, you could also try these:

1. Unregister the script right after you called [`register_block_type()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_block_type/). E.g.

   ```php
   add_action( 'init', function () {
       register_block_type( __DIR__, /* block.json */
           array(
               'render_callback' => 'render_my_block',
               'script'          => 'my-custom-js',
           )
       );

       wp_deregister_script( 'my-custom-js' );
   } );
   ```
2. And manually register the script using the [`wp_enqueue_scripts` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_enqueue_scripts/). E.g.

   ```php
   add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function () {
       wp_register_script( 'my-custom-js', plugins_url( 'build/script.js', __FILE__ ) );
   }, 9 );
   ```

But make sure to use the proper script handle based on your block name. E.g. If the name is `my-plugin/notice`, then the handle would be `my-plugin-notice-script`, i.e. the `/` (slash) is replaced with `-` (dash), and then append a `-script` at the end.

*Tried & tested working in WordPress v5.8.3.*

Comment: Thanks!! I eventually used `is_admin()` and will wait for WP 5.9 support. I wish the official documentation added a note that viewScript was not yet supported lol!

Comment: I actually also *almost* didn't notice that "Since" part.. :D And yes, it's easier to do `'script' => is_admin() ? '' : 'my-custom-js',` .. but if you wanted the block metadata (e.g. in `block.json`) to *always have a non-empty `script` property*, then you could use the "unregister trick" in my answer :)